# Why i get this error The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entitie error in my linq query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new in `entity frame work` and write this query:

```
var query_Books = (from p in Store1.CustomerBooks
                                   where p.CustomerID == query_User[i].id
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       p.BookName,
                                       p.BookCount
                                   }).ToArray();
```

But get this error:

```
Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

and this is my `query_User` query:

```
var query_User = (from p in Store1.CustomerBuys
                              where p.NationalCode.Trim() == NationalCode 
                              select new
                              {
                                  p.id,
                                  p.NationalCode
                              }).ToArray();
```

How can i solve that problem?

Comment: The short version is that LINQ to Entities does not know how to do `array[index]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is unable to convert the `query_User[i]` to an `expression`. Use a temporary variable to work around, something like this:

```
var user = query_User[i];
var query_Books = (from p in Store1.CustomerBooks
                                   where p.CustomerID == user.id
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       p.BookName,
                                       p.BookCount
                                   }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Save this `query_User[i].id` to a temp variable. Then use that temp variable in your query.